# Unable to compile java project with maven

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, compiler-errors, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to build IntelliJ Project with maven on java 16.0.1, but it can't compile my project, although IntelliJ is able to do it successfuly. Before that, I used maven to compile a java 15 project, but I decided to update everything to 16.0.1 because of complete mess with different versions of java on my machine, like I was able to compile but not to run generated .jar files and etc.
`mvn compile` output:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaxiDB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>16.0.1</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`mvn -version` output:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 16.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-50-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

`java -verion` output:

```
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: I think `release` should be `16`, not `16.0.1`

Comment: @JFabianMeier, tried. Same output.

Comment: Not sure if that'll help you but you didn't specify a version for the `maven-jar-plugin`

Comment: @Lino, it didn't help

Comment: I figured out that this error happends not only with 'mvn compile', but with every mvn command

Comment: Ok, so I believe that there is a bug with maven and java 16.0.1. I switched back to 15.0.2 and everything is working fine.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem after upgrading to jdk 16 (maven 3.6). Trying to update to maven 3.8

Comment: Upgrading to maven 3.8 solved the issue. On Ubuntu only 3.6 is available through apt so you'll have to install it manually. This is a pretty good guide: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-maven-on-ubuntu-20-04/ (however, there is a mistake in the JAVA_HOME path in the script)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is your Maven version is too old. It's not compatible with JDK 16.

Try to manually install maven version 3.8.1:

https://maven.apache.org/install.html

This will solve your problem without downgrading your JDK version.

Comment: Try using sdkman to install the JDK and Maven, it will make way easier to manage your JDK and tools versions

Comment: This solved it for me, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running `mvn compile` on Ubuntu 20.10. Running the same maven command on **Ubuntu 21.04** (the latest release) seems to be okay.

You may want to check the version of linux you are running.  If running an older version, upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04.