# Maven error: Unable to load cache item not working on vps but works locally

Tags: java, maven

So I have been trying to compile my maven project on a VPS and made sure that all the versions of maven and jdk are the same as on my system. I even use the same system yet when I compile it on the VPS I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

the output of `mvn -v` is:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-97-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: This `Apache Maven 3.6.3 ..Maven home: /usr/share/maven` show that is not original Apache Maven. This is an installation by the OS. Remove the installation. Download from here: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi (Also I would recommend to use the most recent version of Maven and not an old one)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you maven version is too old, similar to [this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880794/14794107).
Try updating maven manually.
If you have curl installed, run

```
curl -O https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.zip
```

in the directory that should contain maven at the end. Unzip it with

```
unzip apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.zip
```

There should now be a new directory called `apache-maven-3.8.6`. Now add `apache-maven-3.8.6/bin` to your PATH. If you don't know how to do this: add

```
export PATH="$PATH:YOURPATH/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin"
```

to `~/.profile`. But remember to change `YOURPATH` to the path where the `apache-maven-3.8.6` directory is located.

Answer (score 1):

Your maven version and java version are not compatible. You have two options to follow.

**1. Update maven version**
For this may be you can follow steps mentioned in [MrKleeblatt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73108335/11785852) above.

**2. Change java version**
In my case I had to follow this method as I was working in a legacy project.

Step 1: Select java version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1711      auto mode
1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode    
2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

Step 2: Set environment variables

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```